# Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I want to add a button that triggers the action on the Controller inside the razor CSHTML for my ASP.NET project.

Below is the section of the code

```
   <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">

   </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning w-100" 
   asp-action="update" asp-route-id="edit" asp-route-id2="@item.Value">
   <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Update Template</button>
```

And the error I am getting is cannot convert from method group to object.

Comment: First of all, that looks like ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET, those are very different products, so please do not confuse them. Secondly, *where* is the error? From the code it appears to be on `@item.Value`, but it's on you to tell us what `item` is

Comment: Could you please share your code behind and  which line makes such error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to  trigger the action on the Controller with HttpGet,you can use `<a></a>` tag:

```
<a asp-action="update" asp-route-id="edit" asp-route-id2="@item.Value"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Update Template</a>
```

If you want to  trigger the action on the Controller with HttpPost,you can add a form outside button:

```
 <form method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning w-100"
                asp-action="update" asp-route-id="edit" asp-route-id2="@item.Value">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Update Template
        </button>
    </form>
```

> And the error I am getting is cannot convert from method group to
> object.

For the error,I think it may caused by your backend code,may be somewhere you want to get an object from a method,and you forget to add `()`.Here is a demo:

```
    public class A {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
    }
    public A returnObject()
        {
            return new A {  Id=1,Name="a"};
        }
   public void Update()
        {
            A o=returnObject;//Here you need to use A o=returnObject();
        }
```